# Reactjs-popup not taking custom styling for a tooltip modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, tooltip

I am using the "reactjs-popup" library to create a custom style for a tooltip modal using the below syntax, but none of the styling is sticking.

I also tried wrapping the Popup in a div, giving it a className and styling the div, but that didn't work either.

Any help would be very appreciated!

```
     <Popup 
       contentStyle={
       {zIndex: "99"},
       {borderRadius: "10"},
       {wordBreak: "break-all"},
       {width: "500"},
       {height: "500"},
     }
     trigger={ <Button> Click Me! </Button> }
     position="right center"
     on="hover" >

    <Card title="Title goes here" /> 
   </Popup>
```

Comment: Can you create a code sandbox for your code.

Comment: I figured it out... I was using the popup in the wrong spot